# TinkerCAD 7-Segment Display Not Showing on Simulation

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, decoder

I am only on my 5th week trying out TinkerCAD for our Logic Circuits course. We are tasked to create a 7-Segment Display Using Logic Gates only. I did all the boolean expressions needed for each segment using K-MAP, and identified the boolean expression needed to create my circuit.

I am doing the segment A circuit and wiring currently but the 7-Segment didn't output anything after simulating. It should have light on Segment A. Below is the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Simulation]

Here is the link for my TinkerCAD:
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/jdKFk066WBj-stunning-gogo-jofo/editel?sharecode=QOjNbOD_t32_42qIfuNkjnWE0Nt-Yi42CNuwUalVJ_s

How could I solve this? Thanks for those who will help. Sorry if the wirings are a mess, I am still working on it, there are wires running under. Please let me know if there is a problem with the link or you need to know more.

Comment: if you connect it to power and ground (through the resistor) does it light up? If so, then the problem is your circuit

Comment: Ehm, Wacky way to wire 5 IC's on 4 breadboards.  Probe every signal and all power to all IC's.